# Dynamic formula for calculating progress percentage towards a goal?

Tags: excel

Super simple question, but I'm stumped. I'm trying to create a progress bar that shows the % towards a particular goal. This should be dynamic to show the progress even if your goal is negative.

For example, let's say your goal, as a call center manager, is to lower your call time averages to 20 minutes. The current call time average is 45 minutes.

So in this case, lower is better. If my actual values this week has been lowered to 30 minutes (from 45 minutes), so that should technically be 60% progress.

I'm using the following formulas:
for positive goals, `progress = actual value / goal value`
for negative goals, `progress = [ABS(starting value - current value)]/(ABS(goal value - starting value)`

In the example above, the formula for neg goals plugs in as follows:

ABS(45-30)/ABS(20-45) = 15/25 = 0.6 = **60%**. So this makes sense to me.

But things get weird when I'm falling behind. Exmaple, my goal is to obtain 80 customers. I started with 50. However, I happened to lose a lot of them at once and now my current value is 5.

For positive goals, the formula gives progress = 5 / 80 = 0.063 = 6.3%.

But shouldn't this be negative? Like, I have dropped from my original starting value, so my progress cannot be positive. I am obviously missing something in this formula for positive goals, that is not letting me show a scenario where I have fallen really behind from my starting value.

I've scowered excel forums and other boards for someone with a similar question but I have yet to find something... any help pointing this guy in the right direction? I would super appreciate it.

Comment: Add a condition to check whether the actual value is more then the starting value, if it's not, You should process it as negative.

Comment: 5 sales = 6.3% progress as calculated here assumes 0 sales is zero % progress and 80 sales is 100% progress.

Comment: If you have a starting point, 50 in this case, then it would be a % of 50 to 80 scale, not a 0 to 80 scale.  The % is correct, but maybe you want to refine what your question is, and what in means to be less than that starting amount?